# Existing APIs or documentation for accessing Smart Lock systems via custom code? (e.g. Yale, August)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypi, google-smartlockpasswords

I'm looking to use my own **web app to access and unlock a smart lock system** as desired.  (It's for a rental space, and I want people to be able to book their rental slot, get a door code, and for that door code to work only during their rental time to access the space).

I currently have **Google's Nest x Yale lock**, and there doesn't seem to be any ability to get into it with custom programming (at least from my research 5-6 months ago).  Really all I need to be able to do is unlock and lock it... the other logic I will handle with my web app.

I'm wondering **if anyone has any familiarity or knowledge with other smart locking systems (e.g. Yale, August, etc.) that allows for custom programming access, whether via a documented API or otherwise**, that would work well for this situation?

Thank you!

---

These are the current resources I've found, but I can't find much recent dialogue about anyone using any of it:

**YALE**

- https://github.com/bdraco/yalexs
- https://pypi.org/project/yaleclient/
- https://github.com/domwillcode/yale-smart-alarm-client

**AUGUST**

- https://github.com/snjoetw/py-august
- https://nolanbrown.medium.com/august-lock-rest-apis-the-basics-7ec7f31e7874

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Seam](https://seam.co) API. It's a universal API for controlling IoT devices, including smart locks. Here are a couple of guides to get started with August, Yale, Schlage locks:

- August: https://docs.seam.co/latest/device-guides/get-started-with-august-locks
- Yale: https://docs.seam.co/latest/device-guides/get-started-with-yale-locks
- Schlage: https://docs.seam.co/latest/device-guides/get-started-with-schlage-locks

There are Python, Ruby, PHP, Rust,and [JS/Typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/seamapi) client libraries you can use as well.

Comment: I will definitely be looking into this if I get back to doing this at some point in the future, thanks!

Comment: Looks exactly what we all want - but no pricing on their website, always a really bad sign :(